# Regex string with pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

For Regex fans... What I have is this string:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor FOO IO BAR BA"
```

I'd like to extract the **Title**, and an **Array** of the UPPERCASE suffixes:

1. `"Lorem ipsum dolor"`
2. `["FOO", "IO", "BAR", "BA"]`

Here's my attempt:

```
function retrieveGroups( string )
{
   var regexp = new RegExp(/(FOO|BAR|BA|IO)/g);    
   var groups = string.match( regexp ) || [];
   var title  = string.replace( regexp, "" );
   return {title:title, groups:groups};
}
```

results in:

```
title  : "Lorem ipsum dolor    ",
groups : ["FOO" , "IO", "BAR", "BA"]
```

which is great, but It'll not prevent this cases:

```
LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO
```

where in that cas I need only `["FOO"]` in the resulting group.

The rule seems simple...

**Get the title**.
Title could be all uppercase ("LOREM IPSUM").
**Get an array of uppercase suffixes**.
Grouops (FOO,BAR,IO,BA) might not be present in the string.
Don't match suffix if it's not: a suffix and is not lead by a *whitespace*
Start matching from end of string (if possible?) so don't match duplicate Group parameters if encountered (issue example above)

I've also tried to `string.replace(regexp, function(val) ....` but I'm not sure how it could help...

Don't know if it helps but [fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLwzf4ce/). Thank you!

Comment: Why you don't want to match `IO` ?

Comment: cause it's not a suffix (since there's some text after it...) and might be probably part of the title. (I need to minimize errors)

Comment: i think you don't want the title part...

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks for your support, Yes, I need also the title (added to rules now, sorry).

Comment: so, what's the title part for the second example?

Comment: @AvinashRaj well should be all but the last uppercase suffix, therefore: "LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor" (You can see that I need only FOO in the resulting Groups array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
function retrieveGroups( string )
{
   var regexp = new RegExp(/^(.*?)\s*([ A-Z]+)*$/);    
   var result = string.match( regexp ) || [];
   var title  = result[1];
   var groups=result[2].split(" ");
   return {title:title, groups:groups};
}
```

**Edit:**
Here a solution for a fixed set of Uppercase Words:

```
function retrieveGroups( string )
{
   var regexp = new RegExp(/^(.*?)\s*((?:\s|FOO|BAR|IO|BA)+)?$/);    
   var result = string.match( regexp ) || [];
   var title  = result[1];
   var groups=result[2].split(" ");
   return {title:title, groups:groups};
}
```

Comment: Looks promising since I can see the use of `s*` and `*$`. Let me test it! P.S while I'm testing as a side note, I'd like to avoid an uppercase title to be matched in the result array... is that possible? (that's why i've used the group with exact matches `BAR IO FOO BA`)

Comment: When you know which Uppercase Words can be in the groups, you can use this regular expression: `/^(.*?)\s*(?:\s*(FOO|BAR|BAZ))*$/`

Comment: yes, I know exactly what are the suffix parameters. only 4 of them FOO BAR IO BA. Might you pelase update yoru answer? Seems really cool the regex in your comment...

Comment: Amazing... I've tested your second example on all cases and guess what. :) thx

Comment: Did you try it for : LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor (case without the suffix)? That is why I used  Avinash's regex.

Comment: @MaxZoom in the fiddle I've provided? If you remove the unnecessary split() it works. I can always test for truthiness and than split. But in any case I've tested that code all over again and I cannot find any issue.

Comment: @MaxZoom for example in "Name SURNAME DR MAG SCI" (get DR and MAG and SCI) -  or just "Name Surname" (get only the name) - or in "Name SCI Something" (get SCI as part of a name) it works flawelessly!!

Answer (score 3):

To get an array of uppercase suffixes.

```
> "Lorem ipsum dolor FOO IO BAR BA".match(/\b[A-Z]+\b(?!\s+\S*[^A-Z\s]\S*)/g)
[ 'FOO',
  'IO',
  'BAR',
  'BA' ]
> "LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO".match(/\b[A-Z]+\b(?!\s+\S*[^A-Z\s]\S*)/g)
[ 'FOO' ]
```

To get the title array.

```
> "LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO".match(/^.*?(?=\s*\b[A-Z]+\b(?:\s+[A-Z]+\b|$))/g)
[ 'LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor' ]
> "Lorem ipsum dolor FOO IO BAR BA".match(/^.*?(?=\s*\b[A-Z]+\b(?:\s+[A-Z]+\b|$))/g)
[ 'Lorem ipsum dolor' ]
```

**Update:**

```
> "LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO".match(/\b(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b(?!\s+\S*[^A-Z\s]\S*)/g)
[ 'FOO' ]
```

- `\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b` matches `FOO` or `BAR` or `BA` or `IO` and also the following word boundary,
- `(?!\s+\S*[^A-Z\s]\S*)` only if it's not followed by one or more space character , zero or more non-space characters and a character other than a space or an uppercase letter, again followed by zero or more non-space characters. So this fails for `IO` because it's followed by a word which contain atleast one lowercase letter. `(?!...)` called negative lookahead assertion.

---

```
> "Lorem ipsum dolor FOO IO BAR BA".match(/\b(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b(?!\s+\S*[^A-Z\s]\S*)/g)
[ 'FOO',
  'IO',
  'BAR',
  'BA' ]
```

And also, you could use a positive lookahead based regex also. `(?=....)` called positive lookahead assertion.

```
> "LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO".match(/\b(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b(?=\s+(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b|$)/g)
[ 'FOO' ]
```

---

**To get the title array.**

```
> "Lorem ipsum dolor FOO IO BAR BA".match(/^.*?(?=\s*\b(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b(?:\s+(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b|$))/g)
[ 'Lorem ipsum dolor' ]
> "LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO".match(/^.*?(?=\s*\b(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b(?:\s+(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b|$))/g)
[ 'LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor' ]
```

Comment: Nice! Can you please explain how you managed to not to match the `IO` in the latest example? Just a side-question if I may... what if I have only the title (all uppercase) but no matching rules (FOO IO BAR BA) will the title be caught in a match? It's something I'd like to avoid (that's why I've used groups with predefined MATCHES) thx for a response

Comment: i can't understand your side question.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, so, let's say string is exactly: "LOREM IPSUM". there's no suffixes. I think your example will pull IPSUM as a suffix, but it's not. Suffixes can only be FOO BAR IO BA

Comment: then it's so simple. Why you failed to mention this before?

Comment: Guhhhh dunno really sorry, so basically I need to get only uppercase suffixes, (4 of them, FOO BAR BA IO). Suffixes are optional (there might be no suffix at all). Title can be uppercase. What I know is that there's always a whitespace leading a suffix. Basically that's it. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for being a pain in the *foo*, can you just explain what was the most interesting part in your regex to achieve it? Thanks so much!

Comment: sorry, i'll ready to explain my current regex. But i can't able to go further.

Comment: I mean you don't need to explain all the stuff, I have the cheatsheet opened, I know most of them, I'm interested in only the interesting part... Which I can't seem to figure from your code...

Answer (score 2):

By using Avinash's RegEx one can extract all the valid suffixes.
The title would be all text before the first suffix.
So the final JavaScript code will look like below:

```js
var arr = ['Lorem ipsum dolor FOO IO BAR BA', 'LoremFOO ipBAsum IO dolor FOO']

arr.forEach(function(str) {
  var o = retrieveGroups(str);
  alert("Parsed title = " + o.title + ", groups=" + o.groups);
});

function retrieveGroups( string ) {
  var regex = /\b(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b(?=\s+(?:FOO|BAR|BA|IO)\b|$)/g
  var groups = string.match( regex ) || [];
  var title  = string.replace( regex, '').trim();
  return {'title':title, 'groups':groups};
}
```

Here is [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jW4lG9/3)

Comment: Thanks, I gave him up-vote as well for the regex. His regex selects only those suffixes, that are followed by suffix or input end. Pretty simple and neat.

Comment: Yes, if you refer to Torben's answer, although both you and Avinash gave me a good lesson in Regexpezz!! Upvoted and grateful. Thanks a bunch guys!!